# C++: Extra new line after entering a loop?

Tags: c++

I just started learning how to code in January and still very very new at this! My code probably/definitely looks like trash and there's definitely a way to make it more efficient, but I just haven't learned it yet!

I can't seem to find out why there's new line in my display!

The output looks something like this:

```
Student name    Test1    Test2    Test3    Test4    Average    Grade
Ben Smith
90              88       77       55       76.55    A
```

Here's the formation of the text file contents if you want to try.

```
90 88 77 55 Ben Smith  
66 77 66 55 Stuart Bit
```

Here's my full code (the output statements are towards the end):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string name[25], grade[25];
   string dummy;
   int lineNum=0;
   int x,y;

   int table[25][4]{};
   double average[25]{},classAvg[4]{};

   ifstream in;
   in.open("classData.txt");

   while(getline(in, dummy))
   { 
      lineNum++;
   }

   in.close();
   in.open("classData.txt");

   while(!in.eof())
   {
      for(x=0; x<lineNum;x++)
      {
          for(y=0;y<4;y++)
          {
            in>> table[x][y];
          }
          in.ignore(1, '\n');
          getline(in, name[x]);
      }
   }

   in.close();

   for(x=0; x<lineNum;x++)
   {
      for(y=0;y<4;y++)
      {
          average[x] += table[x][y];
      }
      average[x]= average[x]/4;
   }

   for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
   {
      for(int y=0;y<lineNum;y++)
      {
         classAvg[x]+=table[y][x];
      }
      classAvg[x]=classAvg[x]/lineNum;
   }

   for(int x=0;x<lineNum;x++)
   {
      if(average[x]>= 90)
         grade[x]="A";
      else if(average[x]>= 80)
         grade[x]="B";
      else if(average[x]>= 70)
         grade[x]="C";
      else if(average[x]>= 60)
         grade[x]="D";
      else 
         grade[x]="F";
   }

    cout<<setw(20)<<"Student Name"
    <<setw(20)<<"Test 01"<<setw(20)<<"Test 02"
    <<setw(20)<<"Test 03"<<setw(20)<<"Test 04"
    <<setw(20)<<"Average"
    <<setw(20)<<"Grade"<<endl; //Print headers.

   for(int x=0;x<lineNum;x++)
   {
      cout<<setw(20)<<name[x]; //Print all students' names.
      for(int y=0;y<4;y++)
      { 
         cout<<setw(20)<<table[x][y]; //Print 4 tests per student.
      }
      cout<<setw(20)<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<average[x]; //Print average of 4 tests.
      cout<<setw(20)<<grade[x]<<endl; //Print the grade of the student.
   }
}
```

Comment: Try to use a debugger

Comment: The code `Test 01` does not produce the output `Test1`. Nobody wants to try decipher what you failed to copy/paste correctly.

Comment: To follow Danh's suggestion, [this article is a good one](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You are ignoring the newline character, but does your file contain Windows line endings?

Comment: Just did a quick search on google on how to use a debugger and problem solved! Thanks @Danh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing a good job for a first time programmer!
The newline that appears in your output comes from your input file.

With:

```
getline(in, name[x]);
```

you read all characters including the newline at the end.

You could try to trim name[x] afterwards.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the problem! I had thought getline() would discard the newline character since it does it from user input. Apparently not when reading a text file! Thank you for pointing it out!